# Spawning an interactive telnet session from a shell script

Tags: bash, telnet

I'm trying to write a script to allow me to log in to a console servers 48 ports so that I can quickly determine what devices are connected to each serial line.

Essentially I want to be able to have a script that, given a list of hosts/ports, telnets to the first device in the list and leaves me in interactive mode so that I can log in and confirm the device, then when I close the telnet session, connects to the next session in the list.

The problem I'm facing is that if I start a telnet session from within an executable bash script, the session terminates immediately, rather than waiting for input.

For example, given the following code:

```
$ cat ./telnetTest.sh
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
        telnet $line
done
$
```

When I run the command 'echo "hostname" | testscript.sh' I receive the following output:

```
$ echo "testhost" | ./telnetTest.sh
Trying 192.168.1.1...
Connected to testhost (192.168.1.1).
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
$
```

Does anyone know of a way to stop the telnet session being closed automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to redirect the Terminal input to the `telnet` process.  This should be `/dev/tty`.  So your script will look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for HOST in `cat`
do
  echo Connecting to $HOST...
  telnet $HOST </dev/tty
done
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you should look at **expect** program. It`s present in all modern linux distros. Here is some exmaple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn telnet $host_name
expect {
   "T0>"                {}
   -re "Connection refused|No route to host|Invalid argument|lookup failure"
                        {send_user "\r******* connection error, bye.\n";exit}
   default              {send_user "\r******* connection error (telnet timeout),
 bye.\n";exit}
}
send "command\n"
expect -timeout 1 "something"
```

**spawn** command start remote login program (telnet, ssh, netcat etc)

**expext** command used to... hm.. expect something from remote session

**send** - sending commands

**send_user** - to print comments to stdout

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Dave - it was the TTY redirection that I was missing.

The complete solution I used, for those who are interested:

```
#!/bin/bash

TTY=`tty` # Find out what tty we have been invoked from.
for i in `cat hostnames.csv` # List of hosts/ports
do
        # Separate port/host into separate variables
        host=`echo $i | awk -F, '{ print $1 }'`
        port=`echo $i | awk -F, '{ print $2 }'`
        telnet $host $port < $TTY # Connect to the current device
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Telnet to Server using Shell Script Example:

`Test3.sh` File:

```
#!/bin/sh

#SSG_details is file from which script will read ip adress and uname/password
#to telnet.

SSG_detail=/opt/Telnet/SSG_detail.txt

cat $SSG_detail | while read ssg_det ; do

   ssg_ip=`echo $ssg_det|awk '{print $1}'`
   ssg_user=`echo $ssg_det|awk '{print $2}'`
   ssg_pwd=`echo $ssg_det|awk '{print $3}'`


   echo " IP to telnet:" $ssg_ip
   echo " ssg_user:" $ssg_user
   echo " ssg_pwd:" $ssg_pwd

   sh /opt/Telnet/Call_Telenet.sh $ssg_ip $ssg_user $ssg_pwd 

done


exit 0
```

The `Call_Telenet.sh` script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

DELAY=1 
COMM1='config t'                 #/* 1st commands to be run*/
COMM2='show run'
COMM3=''
COMM4=''
COMM5='exit'
COMM6='wr'
COMM7='ssg service-cache refresh all'
COMM8='exit'                     #/* 8th command to be run */


telnet $1 >> $logfile 2>> $logfile |&
sleep $DELAY
echo -p $2 >> $logfile 2>> $logfile
sleep $DELAY
echo -p $3 >> $logfile 2>> $logfile
sleep $DELAY
echo -p $4 >> $logfile 2>> $logfile
sleep $DELAY
echo -p $5 >> $logfile 2>> $logfile
sleep $DELAY

sleep $DELAY
sleep $DELAY
sleep $DELAY
echo -p $COMM7 >> $logfile 2>> $logfile
sleep $DELAY
echo -p $COMM8 >> $logfile 2>> $logfile
sleep $DELAY

exit 0
```

Run the above file as follows:

```
$> ./test3.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try bash -i to force the session to be in interactive mode.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your example is that you link the input of your script (and indirectly of `telnet`) to the output of the `echo`. So after `echo` is done and `telnet` is started, there is no more input to read. A simple fix could be to replace `echo "testhost"` by `{ echo "testhost"; cat; }`.

Edit: `telnet` doesn't seem to like taking input from a pipe. However, `netcat` does and is probably just suitable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

@muz 
I have a setting with ssh, no telnet, so i can't test if your problem is telnet related, but running the following script logs me successively to the different machines asking for a password.

```
for i in adele betty
do
ssh all@$i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If your environment is X11-based, a possibility is to open an xterm running telnet:

```
xterm -e telnet $host $port
```

Operations in xterm are interactive and shell script is halted until xterm termination.

Answer (score 0):

Try these links.

http://planetozh.com/blog/2004/02/telnet-script/

http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/193-telnet-script.html

```
#!/bin/sh
( echo open hostname
sleep 5
echo username
sleep 1
echo password
sleep 1
echo some more output, etc. ) | telnet
```

They worked for me :D